# Text revision gem for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Is there a text revision gem for Rails? Preferably I'd like it to keep revision history of text, some type of access control with moderators, and just overall Wikipedia-like.

Answer (score 1):

I've used papertrail for versioninghttps://github.com/airblade/paper_trail It's very easy to add and set up.

You could combine it with cancan, Or some other authorisation strategy for access control.